# When is $\frac{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+a}}$ defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> When is
>
> $$u_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+a}}$$
>
> defined?

I understand that it must be defined iff: ($n+a>0$ and $\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n>0$)

But then the correction was: ($n>-a$ and $n\ge 2$)

But I managed to get:

\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n>0\\
\iff& \sqrt{n}>-(-1)^n\\
\iff& n>(-1)^{2n}\\
\iff&n>1
\end{align*}

did I missed something?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer than $n\gt1$ is the same as $n\ge2$

Answer (score 1):

If $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots,$ then $\sqrt{n}$ is perfectly defined.

Now you have to ensure that
$$
u_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+a}}
$$ is defined, thus you must have
$$
n+a\geq0 \quad \text{and} \quad \sqrt{n+a} \neq 0,
$$ which gives that $u_n$ is defined for

> $$
> n \in \{0,1,2,3,\cdots\} \cap \{n>-a\}.
> $$